# Is the argument below valid??

Tags: logic

The following material is obtained form How to prove it by Daniel J Velleman. The book has asked to check the validity of the following argument without using truth table. The argument goes like this:

*Either John or Bill is telling the truth. Either Sam or Bill is lying. Therefore, either John is telling the truth or Sam is lying*.

What I think:
In the first statement either John or Sam is telling the truth. In the next statement we see Bill on Sam is lying.So what I am trying to say is does the statement regarding Bill matter for the given argument to be valid since conclusion does not have anything to do with Bill. Now assuming Both premises true , can't we tell John  is telling the truth or Sam is lying making the argument valid?

Comment: What do you mean with " truth regarding John and Sam follows from the premises " ?

Comment: I can't follow your argument. Break it into two cases:   from the first statement, we know that either John is telling the truth or Bill is (or both, but let's toss that in with the first case).  In the first case, we are instantly done.  In the second case we move to the second premise and...

Comment: @curiosityzero Can you please integrate that comment you just made into your Post? (and I think you meant to say that the conclusion has nothing to do with Bil, rather than Sam)

Comment: yes I was trying to say that. Thank you for reminding that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, and here's an easier way to see it. "(J truth) or (S lie)" is equivalent to "If not (J truth), then (S lie)". So, let's assume "not (J truth)". By the first statement, we obtain (B truth), which combines with the second statement to imply (S lie).

We have now proven "(J truth) or (S lie)".

Comment: I wanted to see if my reasoning was correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> In the first statement either John or Bill is telling the truth. In the next statement we see Bill on Sam is lying.So what I am trying to say is does the statement regarding Bill matter for the given argument to be valid since conclusion does not have anything to do with Bill. Now assuming Both premises true , can't we tell John is telling the truth or Sam is lying making the argument valid?

You wish to determine the validity for the argument: ${j\vee b, \neg s\vee\neg b\vdash j\vee \neg s}$

In classical logic we can make an *argument by cases*, since it is axiomatic that Bill is either *lying **or** telling the truth*.

- Assuming Bill is lying, then the first premise means John is telling the truth (by disjunctive syllogism), or Sam is lying (by disjunction introduction).
  $$\begin{split}\neg b, j\vee b & \vdash j\\ j&\vdash j\vee\neg s\\ \hline \neg b, j\vee b &\vdash j\vee\neg s \end{split}$$
- Assuming Bill is telling the truth, then the second premise means Sam is lying (by disjunctive syllogism), or John is telling the truth (by disjunction introduction)$$\begin{split}b, \neg s\vee \neg b & \vdash \neg s\\ \neg s&\vdash j\vee\neg s\\\hline b, \neg s\vee \neg b &\vdash j\vee\neg s \end{split}$$
- Either case derives that either John is telling the truth or Sam is lying.

$$\begin{split} &\vdash \neg b\vee b\\ \neg b, j\vee b&\vdash j\vee\neg s\\b, \neg s\vee \neg b & \vdash j\vee\neg s\\\hline j\vee b, \neg s\vee\neg b& \vdash j\vee \neg s\end{split}$$

Comment: I have not reached the part that has introduced those concept so  I am having trouble following your argument though I am sure  this will be a good refrence when I do. Thank you for your effort

Comment: If its not Bill, then its John, or if it is Bill, then it i
s not Sam, so therefore it is either John or